# Linked List Head Dynamic Allocation -- C

Tags: c, data-structures, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I am working on a small learning project in C but am having troubles implementing a head node that will hold the first data value of the data set. I am supposed to take an unsorted linked list and use it to implement a sorted linked list. It should be split into two functions like the example below.

My problem arises when allocating memory for the head pointer node on the heap. It always seems to make an extra head node with a data value of 0 (0 is not in the data set, but potentially could be) when using malloc.

```
    struct node* create_sorted_list(struct node *head)
    {
       struct node * curr = head;
       struct node * sorted_head = malloc(sizeof(struct node));

       while(curr != NULL){
          add_item_sorted(sorted_head, curr->data);
          curr=curr->next;
       }   
       return sorted_head;
    }



    struct node* add_item_sorted(struct node *sorted_head, int data)
    {
       struct node * curr = sorted_head;
       struct node * newN;    
       while(curr->next != NULL){

          if(data > curr->next->data){
             curr=curr->next;
          }
          else{
             newN = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
             newN->data = data;
             newN->next = curr->next;
             curr->next = newN;
             return sorted_head; 
          }
       }   
       newN = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
       curr->next = newN;
       newN->data = data;
       return sorted_head;
    }



    int main(int argc, char *argv[])
    { 
        ......
        struct node * sorted_head = create_sorted_list(head);

        //head in this case comes from an unsorted linked list with the 
        //same data values. Using head linked list to make sorted_head.
    }
```

My output is something like this : 0 -> 56 -> 35 -> 98 -> end
When it should be:                 56 -> 35 -> 98 -> end

I have reason to believe that the extra node is a result of one to many calls of malloc, however I cannot find the right solution.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks Guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Function `create_sorted_list` is already wrong.

In general `head` can be equal to `NULL`. However there is created `sorted_head` in the function that is not equal to NULL.

```
struct node* create_sorted_list(struct node *head)
    {
       struct node * curr = head;
       struct node * sorted_head = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
       while(curr != NULL){
           //...
       }   
       return sorted_head;
    }
```

Moreover its data members are not initialized. So if function `add_item_sorted` will be called for such node then access to the data member `next` will result in undefined behavior of the program.

```
  struct node* add_item_sorted(struct node *sorted_head, int data)
    {
       struct node * curr = sorted_head;
       struct node * newN;    
       while(curr->next != NULL){
             ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

And at least you have to write

```
  while(curr != NULL){
      sorted_head = add_item_sorted(sorted_head, curr->data);
      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

The functions can be written as it is shown in the following demonstrative program

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct node
{
    int data;
    struct node *next;
};  

struct node* add_item( struct node *head, int data )
{
    struct node *tmp = malloc( sizeof( struct node ) );
    tmp->data = data;
    tmp->next = head;

    return tmp;
}

struct node* add_item_sorted( struct node *sorted_head, int data );

struct node * create_sorted_list( struct node *head )
{
    struct node *sorted_head = NULL;

    for ( ; head != NULL; head = head->next )
    {
        sorted_head = add_item_sorted( sorted_head, head->data );
    }   

    return sorted_head;
}

struct node* add_item_sorted( struct node *sorted_head, int data )
{
    if ( sorted_head == NULL || !( sorted_head->data < data ) )
    {
        struct node *tmp = malloc( sizeof( struct node ) );

        tmp->data = data;
        tmp->next = sorted_head;
        sorted_head = tmp;
    }
    else
    {
       struct node *current = sorted_head;

        while ( current->next != NULL && current->data < data )
        {
            current = current->next;
        }

        struct node *tmp = malloc( sizeof( struct node ) );
        tmp->data = data;
        tmp->next = current->next;
        current->next = tmp;
    }

    return sorted_head;
}

void display( struct node *head )
{
    for ( ; head != NULL; head = head->next )
    {
        printf( "%d ", head->data );
    }
    printf( "\n" );
}

#define N   10

int main( void ) 
{
    struct node *head = NULL;

    for ( int i = 1; i <= N; i++ ) head = add_item( head, i );

    display( head );

    struct node *sorted_head = create_sorted_list( head );
    display( sorted_head );

    return 0;
}
```

Rge program output is

```
10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
```

Comment: Thanks much! I tried setting the sortedList head to NULL in create_sorted_list before posting this but found always ran into seg faults. Any chance you could elaborate on the "undefined behavior" that my example code was running into?

Comment: @Lamar As data member next is not initialized then the condition in the loop while(curr->next != NULL){ can have a random value.

Comment: I see! Thanks for the clarification

Answer (score 1):

I believe it is happening because in your `add_item_sorted` function, you are accessing the list as if there is a dummy head node (you are starting with checking `cur->next->data`, where you should be actually checking `cur->data`).

When you `malloc` a node, it might be holding a `0` or any other value in its data field. So, in your case, `sorted_head` is holding `0` in its data field. Now, according to your example, you try to insert the value `56`. In `add_item_sorted` function, you first try to access `cur->next->data`, which is NULL. So, a new node is inserted after this sorted_head.